# Turn 1 C++ Loop into 2

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I need a little programming help for class. I wrote the code below, but my teacher says I need to utilize 2 for loops when reading the data file. I'm not sure how to do that... any suggestions?

My Code:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("dive.txt");
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    infile >> contestantNames[i][0] >> contestantNames[i][1] >> judgeScores[i][0] >> judgeScores[i][1] >> judgeScores[i][2] >> judgeScores[i][3] >> judgeScores[i][4] >> judgeScores[i][5] >> judgeScores[i][6] >> judgeScores[i][7];
infile.close();
```

Comment: Your teacher probably wants you to use two nested loops, rather than going from 0 to 7 by hand.

Comment: can you please post your example for 100 contestants? (with `contestantNames[100][100]`)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of repetitiously writing

```
infile >> contestantNames[0][0] >> contestantNames[0][1] >> judgeScores[0][0] >> judgeScores[0][1] >> judgeScores[0][2] >> judgeScores[0][3] >> judgeScores[0][4] >> judgeScores[0][5] >> judgeScores[0][6] >> judgeScores[0][7];
infile >> contestantNames[1][0] >> contestantNames[1][1] >> judgeScores[1][0] >> judgeScores[1][1] >> judgeScores[1][2] >> judgeScores[1][3] >> judgeScores[1][4] >> judgeScores[1][5] >> judgeScores[1][6] >> judgeScores[1][7];
infile >> contestantNames[2][0] >> contestantNames[2][1] >> judgeScores[2][0] >> judgeScores[2][1] >> judgeScores[2][2] >> judgeScores[2][3] >> judgeScores[2][4] >> judgeScores[2][5] >> judgeScores[2][6] >> judgeScores[2][7];
infile >> contestantNames[3][0] >> contestantNames[3][1] >> judgeScores[3][0] >> judgeScores[3][1] >> judgeScores[3][2] >> judgeScores[3][3] >> judgeScores[3][4] >> judgeScores[3][5] >> judgeScores[3][6] >> judgeScores[3][7];
infile >> contestantNames[4][0] >> contestantNames[4][1] >> judgeScores[4][0] >> judgeScores[4][1] >> judgeScores[4][2] >> judgeScores[4][3] >> judgeScores[4][4] >> judgeScores[4][5] >> judgeScores[4][6] >> judgeScores[4][7];
infile >> contestantNames[5][0] >> contestantNames[5][1] >> judgeScores[5][0] >> judgeScores[5][1] >> judgeScores[5][2] >> judgeScores[5][3] >> judgeScores[5][4] >> judgeScores[5][5] >> judgeScores[5][6] >> judgeScores[5][7];
infile >> contestantNames[6][0] >> contestantNames[6][1] >> judgeScores[6][0] >> judgeScores[6][1] >> judgeScores[6][2] >> judgeScores[6][3] >> judgeScores[6][4] >> judgeScores[6][5] >> judgeScores[6][6] >> judgeScores[6][7];
```

you wrote a `for` loop.

Where else is there repetition?

Answer (score 2):

Your two for loops would be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    infile >> contestantNames[i][0] >> contestantNames[i][1];
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
        infile >> judgeScores[i][j];
    }
}
```

Your instructor want you to simplify that continuous line of judgeScores into a for loop which is much simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("dive.txt");

for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
  infile >> contestantNames[i][0] >> contestantNames[i][1];

  // The next part is what your teacher was talking about.
  // You wrote judgeScores[i][0] >> judgeScores[i][1] >> ...
  // seven times, which is pretty redundant. Programmers are *extremely* lazy
  // so we loop constantly, wherever possible:

  for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
  {
     infile >> judgeScores[i][j];
  }
}

infile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your instructor means to loop once over all the contestants, and loop again to input each contestant's information (name and score.)

So try something like this:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("dive.txt");
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    infile >> contestantNames[i][0] >> contestantNames[i][1];
    for (int j = 0; i <= 7; j++) {
         infile >> judgeScores[i][j];
    }
}
infile.close();
```

Note: the brackets aren't required, since each statement consists of one line.  This is the exception to the rule, however - if there is more than 1 statement in the `for` loop, brackets *would* be required.  (As you may know.)

Answer (score 0):

You teacher probably wants you to consider the case when there are more than two contenstants.
Something along the lines of

```
nc = 6;  // the number of contenstans
for (int c=0; c<nc; c++) {
  // other for loop here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprise you teacher with even three loops:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("dive.txt");
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        infile >> contestantNames[i][j];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
       infile >> judgeScores[i][j];
    }
}
infile.close();
```

Comment: Any suggestion that starts with "surprise your teacher" should probably immediately send up red flags.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Why not?  I meant in a good way.  As you can see, this version is the only one here, that allows for easier change in number of `contestants`.  If I were the teacher, I would have liked to see this version.

Answer (score 0):

Put a while loop checking for the end of file (EOF) in case there are more than 6 lines. Test cases for bad data wouldn't hurt either.